# React's setState seems to strip array of items

Tags: reactjs

This is really weird as I've been using setState for months and this is the first time I've ever seen this issue. I have some code that simply sets a state property to another object. In the object to be set I have one property that is an array called GroupModel. The strange thing is once this object get's set in setState, the property GroupModel get's converted down to an object and I lose it's members. I have other array properties in this object and they are not affected.

```
// just before the call to setState I check newUserGridConfig and find that its child property, 
// GroupModel, is indeed an array and has the expected child elment.
self.setState({ localGridConfig: newUserGridConfig }, () => {

    // once setState completes I check self.state.localGridConfig.GroupModel and 
    // find that it is now an object (i.e. [object Object]). 
    // I then check newUserGridConfig.GroupModel and 
    // it is still an array and has the expected element in it
    var response = self.updateUserGridConfigurationStore(self.state.localGridConfig, 
    saveNetwork);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this was happening because setState is both asynchronous and not guaranteed to run immediately. So I had some other code that managed to just slip in between and set the property first.